# JAXB Namespace issue

Tags: namespaces, jaxb

This question is for Mr.Blaise Doughan on JAXB Namespace

I have situation where,

Have a sample.xsd (old version - no namespace ). Generated JAXB classes using the XJC for the same XSD file. I got one example that uses the JAXB classes to unmarshal the XML data file , based on the XSD.
The sample.xsd file got changed (new version - added namespace). Again generated JAXB classes using the XJC for the new XSD file. The Example is updated so that it can now work for new XSD file

Now I got a situation , where iam getting XML data file based on old XSD and I would like to use the updated example file to unmarshal the old XML data.

One solution I could see , generating two object factory one with namespace and one without namespace. Can we do that? if so I can use the appropriate Object factory based on the my XML data I get.

Or would like to know , how can I generate JAXB classes for both XSD files , but XJC is not generating , it shows error - No changes detected in schema or binding files - skipping source generation.

Can I create a wrapper over the new Object Factory so that it can handle both ?

Please do provide me with some solution so that I can unmarshal the old file with new JAXB classes. Can

Answer (score 1):

### Apply a Namespace

In the case where the input XML does not have a namespace you can leverage a SAX `XMLFilter` to apply a namespace.

```java
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl;

public class NamespaceFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.example.com/customer";

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName);
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName, atts);
    }

}
```

### Do the Unmarshal

The unmarshalling is done leveraging JAXB's `UnmarshallerHandler` as the `ContentHandler`

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create the JAXBContext
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        // Create the XMLFilter
        XMLFilter filter = new NamespaceFilter();

        // Set the parent XMLReader on the XMLFilter
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        filter.setParent(xr);

        // Set UnmarshallerHandler as ContentHandler on XMLFilter
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller
                .getUnmarshallerHandler();
        filter.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);

        // Parse the XML
        InputSource xml = new InputSource("src/blog/namespace/sax/input.xml");
        filter.parse(xml);
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshallerHandler.getResult();

        // Marshal the Customer object back to XML
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

}
```

### For More Information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/applying-namespace-during-jaxb-unmarshal.html

Comment: Hi, I did the same as suggested by you. Applied the namespace for the output we won’t get the namespace. But I found another issue; my question is in below 2 comments, request to read both.
Old Schema has no namespace. New Schema has namespace and it even imports another schema.  When I run the example, taking the XML output that has no namespace and try to Marshall with JAXB objects that have namespace after applying Namespace Filter, I get below output. My intent is to have the same complete XML output with namespace. But iam not getting that, I get only below two lines.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:benchmarks xmlns:ns2="xxxxx/XMLSchema/application" xmlns:ns3="xxxxx/XMLSchema/applicationtypes"/> [Unable to put the actual schema URL - it is not allowing me to put the http url , so intest kept xxxxx)
Comment1
The old XML Schema is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs=" xxxxx/www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="appinfo" type="appInfo"/>
No Namespace for this schema

Comment: Comment 2
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs= xxxxx/2001/XMLSchema          xmlns:tns=" xxxxx /XMLSchema/application" targetNamespace=" xxxxx /XMLSchema/application" version="1.0">

<xs:import namespace=" xxxxx/XMLSchema/applicationtypes" schemaLocation="applicationtypes.xsd"/> 

<xs:element name="appinfo" type="tns:appInfo"/>

Namespace added to schema and even one import for another schema.

Comment: Hi - can you help with my question